# Can't make a synchronous REST call in jQuery 1.8+

Tags: jquery, ajax, rest, asynchronous, get

As of jQuery 1.8 the async:fals option for the $.ajax function has been deprecated. This was my go to method for making REST calls. Can any one demonstrate a method for making a synchronous REST call in jQuery 1.8+. I tried using the $.get function but couldn't figure out how to set data:jsonp to avoid the access control origin issue.

Comment: Any reason why you can't use async?

Comment: Ben, you have to bite the bullet and stop trying to do synchronous ajax. It was never available in all browsers anyway.

Comment: If the functionality has been "deprecated" that means it is still available, it just isn't recommended - so you can still use it, bearing in mind it may be removed in a later version. But assuming it does get removed, you could code your own Ajax function. (Having said that, I agree with the others: why can't you use async?)